Can we decompose two separable security notions?
If two security definitions $A$ and $B$ are separable, meaning $A$ does not imply $B$ and $B$ does not imply $A$, is it possible to find three other security definitions $C$, $D$, and $E$ such that $C + D = A$ and $D + E = B$?
In cryptographic literature, it is common to encounter different security definitions for a particular application system (protocol), which we may denote as $A$ and $B$. Both $A$ and $B$ tend to be complex, possibly due to differences in expression style, design objectives, or definitional choices. They also often differ in terms of complexity and usability. For instance, when considering security against chosen-plaintext attacks, there are four different definitions: left-or-right, find-then-guess, real-or-random, and semantic security (see 'A Concrete Security Treatment of Symmetric Encryption' by Mihir Bellare et al., 1997, FOCS). When both $A$ and $B$ are complex (as modern cryptographic application systems are becoming increasingly complex), and counter-examples prove that they are separable, i.e., neither can imply the other, is it possible to further decompose $A$ and $B$ such that $D$ represents the common security property of $A$ and $B$, but is non-empty, while $C$ and $E$ respectively express the unique security properties of $A$ and $B$? Is this question well-founded, and is there a research motivation in cryptography for such an inquiry?

What's you requirement for a security definition? Let C=A, E=B and let D be the "security" definition that doesn't require anything,

@Maeher  I have updated the description of the question. D represents the common security property of A and B and is non-empty. C and E are also non-empty.
